# Could not instantiate bean class [com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.BindResult]: No default constructor found; nested exception is

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to get list of key and value pairs and try to save the values through a form.

This is the frontend code

```
<form:form id="update-user-form"
                                    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/add-app-settings"
                                    commandName="appTypeSettings" class="form-horizontal">


                                    <c:forEach var="key" items="${appTypeSettingsKey}">
                                        <%--                <a href="#panelDecription" style="cursor: pointer;">${key.setting_key}</a> --%>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>

                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <form:errors path="setting_key" cssClass="error" />
                                                <form:label path="setting_key" id="setting_key_error"
                                                    cssClass="error"></form:label>
                                            </div>
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">${key.setting_key}</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <form:input path="setting_value" cssClass="form-control" id=""
                                                    maxlength="50" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </c:forEach>
                                    <c:if test="${not empty appTypeSettingsKey}">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div>
                                                    <!-- <a class="btn btn-primary m-r-5" style="float: right"
                                                        href="#modal-dialog" >Save</a> -->
                                                    <form:button>submit</form:button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </c:if>
                                </form:form>
```

However, when I try to save the values I get an error. Before, excute the body of following requestmapping method, I get an exception.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add-app-settings", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addSettings(Model model, final HttpServletRequest request, BindResult result,@ModelAttribute("appTypeSettings") TVAppsForm settings) {
    ModelAndView addapp = new ModelAndView("add-app");
    //System.out.println("");
    return addapp;
}
```

Here is the exception,

```
2016-01-12 11:06:01 ERROR AppErrorHandler:57 - The following Exception was thrown 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.BindResult]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.BindResult.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.BindResult.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2892)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2058)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    ... 40 more
2016-01-12 11:06:01 INFO  AppErrorHandler:63 - Exited : ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex)
```

I assume, one problem is I try to bind an object but I get a list of objects. Can anybody help me to find the issu?

Comment: typo? shouldn't this be `org.springframework.validation.BindingResult`?

Comment: No, this is copy pasting

Comment: Even so, I think you're using the wrong class/interface. Replace the current import statement with the one above. [Spring's](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html)

Comment: i mean the original error is a typo. say you type BindResult accidentally (easy to do), the IDE brings up some match that has nothing to do with spring-mvc, you ok it without looking closely, and here you go.

Comment: Thanks guys, it is wrong import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says NoDefaultConstructor which means that it doesn't have a constructor that takes no arguments. In general if you get this it means that something is trying to instantiate that class in order to use it to do something else but the thing that's trying to instantiate it relies on there being a constructor with no arguments so it can create the object because it doesn't know what on earth the arguments are supposed to be. This is a big gotcha in hibernate, but i'm guessing that's unrelated here.

Anyway, look at what is instantiating your BindResult class and like the others suggested, check if it's actually the right class to begin with or if you haven't imported something else by mistake.